# Gson transform a field into multiple fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Say I have serialized the following object as json string:

```
class Person {
    public final String name;
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
}

Person p = new Person("Bob Falaway");
JsonObject json = gson.toJsonTree(p, Person.class).getAsJsonObject();
```

Now I want to deserialize it, but I want to split split the name into two fields, `firstName` and `lastName`. How do I do this?

I want the end to result in a class similar to:

```
class RefinedPerson {
    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;

    public String toString() { return String.format("%s %s", firstName, lastName); }
}
```

Is this at all possible with Gson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your own `JsonSerializer` for the type (or `TypeAdapter` if you'd prefer)?

Something like:

```
@JsonAdapter(PersonSerializer.class)
class Person {
    private final String name;
    Person(final String name) {
        // Some validation...
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Where your serialiser looks something like:

```
class PersonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public JsonObject serialise(final Person src,
                                final Type personType,
                                final JsonSerializationContext context) {

        final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        final String[] names = src.getName().split(" ");
        // Some validation...

        json.addProperty("firstName", names[0]);
        json.addProperty("lastName", names[1]);
        return json;
    }
}
```